# About interrupt context,atomic context and process context in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt

As I know, we can verify that we are in interrupt context by involving `in_interrupt()` in linux kernel. And the implementation of the `in_interrupt()` function is counting by the `thread_info->preempt_count` when entering or exiting hardirq or softirq. So, when the `in_interrupt()` return none-zero, it indicates that we are processing in hardirq or softirq.

However, My question is when we involve the `local_bh_disable()` function, it does increase the `thread_info->preempt_count`, so the `in_interrupt()` function return none-zero. Thus, how could we determine if we are in the interrupt context now. And in my opinion, atomic context is that local interrupt is disabled

Here is a circumstances that I'm now in kernel mode, and I want to access the userland address space, but I don't know whether running in the process context or interrupt context, because of accessing userland address space in interrupt context is invalid, so I want to determine whether being in the process context by involving the `in_interrupt()` function. Then I got the return value greater than zero, thus, I will think that I am now in interrupt context and won't access the userland. However, maybe there are some function that imply involving the `local_bh_disable` to increase the `thread_info->preempt_count` to disable the sortirq, but in fact that, we are in process context and just disabling the softirq, thus, we could access the userland address space safely but we make a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

There are several interesting functions in [preempt_mask.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/preempt_mask.h):

- in_irq(): hardware interrupt
- in_softirq(): Are we in a softirq context?
- in_interrupt(): Interrupt context?
- in_nmi(): Are we in NMI context?
- in_atomic(): Are we running in atomic context?  WARNING: this macro cannot always detect atomic context

---

Please note that in normal circumstances, a driver should not need to use any of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think in_interrupt() is a BAD design!

If your codes ruuning in process context, you did not need to invoke in_interrupt().

in_serving_softirq() indicates you are in real softirq context do_softirq() not local_bh_disable().